# Java: Why Unicode characters not support in my Distro but is in another one?

Tags: java, unicode

I am using [Debian 10.5](https://www.debian.org/) with Cinnamon Desktop and am trying to display unicode icons in my Java program.

Example :
When I try to use [this unicode character](https://unicode-table.com/en/23F1/), it displays fine in Windows 10, Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome 3 but not with my Debian.
My hunch so far is that the default fonts of those 3 systems being different, maybe the default font of my Debian (Sans Regular 9) doesn't support this unicode character ?
Any idea if this is the actual issue and how to remedy this issue ?
Thanks

Display in Debian
[image: Debian]

Display in Win10
[image: Win10]

Display in ubuntu
[image: ubuntu]

Answer (score 0):

You're probably right about not having the right font package installed. I'd consult the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fonts), it's very comprehensive about fonts generally but you'll often not be able to copy the commands literally.

This [page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Java_Runtime_Environment_fonts) might help you as well.